# Fine tuning code-bison model on Google Vertex AI

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-generativeai

I am trying to train a "code-bsion" model in Google vertex AI using "Generative studio" and custom code as mentioned in "https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/generative-ai/models/tune-code-models". Used the exact same json as the example:

```
{"input_text": "How to create a product in Python with the Cloud Vision API?, "output_text": "code...."}
```

When I deploy this model and ask the same prompt "How to create a product in Python with the Cloud Vision API?", it does not give me the code block in the "output_text". It gives something else.

I also plan to use my own code templates. but, the the code-bison model does not even answer  any of the "input_text" questions. It gives some other answer.

Comment: Hi @teeboy, Could you provide the output that you are getting or any error message if you are facing ?

Comment: Like I mentioned in my question, there are no errors. The model is successfully deployed. It does not answer questions based on my training data

Comment: Hi @teeboy, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.